# mysql difference between dates expressed in years

Tags: mysql, date

I've been using the following for some time to avoid the fact that `DATEDIFF` doesn't account for leap years.

```
"select 
  year(now()) 
  - year(`birthdate`) 
  - (date_format(now(), '%m%d') < date_format(`birthdate`, '%m%d');"
```

But I've never really understood exactly how it works, in particular, what the `<` operator does here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` is a comparison operator.

So that last line is evaluated as a boolean expression. The expression on the left is being compared to the expression on the right, and the comparison is returning either NULL, 0 or 1. (MySQL returns 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.)

The net effect of that last line is that's subtracting either a `"0"` or a `"1"` (if birthdate is not null.)

To see this in action, try running this query:

```
SELECT '0501' < '1031' AS foo
```

The result of the boolean expression can be referenced in another expression, for example:

```
SELECT 24 - ( '0501' < '1031' ) AS foo
```

---

If `birthdate` is non-null, the expression:

```
(date_format(now(),'%m%d') < date_format(`birthdate`,'%m%d')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
IF((date_format(now(),'%m%d') < date_format(`birthdate`,'%m%d'),1,0)
```

and equivalent to:

```
CASE WHEN (date_format(now(),'%m%d') < date_format(`birthdate`,'%m%d')
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP does not understand how string operands are compared numerically.

Comment: I think I got it now, so if the date (mmdd) already passed we need to subtract one more year for the correct total. That's pretty cool

Comment: @andrew: it's convenient shorthand, though it can be a bit puzzling the first time you run across it. The "trick" is that MySQL evaluates boolean expressions as 0, 1 or NULL, and the result can be used like any other integer.

Comment: @andrew: I'm not vouching that the value returned by the entire expression is a valid representation of "age"; I was just explaining what MySQL was doing with the **`<`**, how that was being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The last boolean part (< comparsion) makes difference between asking before/after birthday. (Adds 1 OR 0)

Try:

`SELECT 10 - 7 - true` = 2

`SELECT 10 - 7 - false` = 3